# How to change the base function in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio, tabular-editor

my calculations are as below.

```
Base = Sum( mydf[amount])
Function1 = Calculate([Base],....)
Function2 = Calculate([Base],....)
Function3 = Calculate([Base],....)
Total = Function1 + Function2 + Function3
```

I would like change my Base functions as follows

```
   Base_1 = SUMX(  mydf, mydf[amount]*1 )
   Base_2 = SUMX(  mydf, mydf[amount]*2 ) 
   and save them as Total_1 and Total_2
```

If I wanna change the base function only once, I would just change it and I would write `Total_1` instead of `Total`.
But how can i store it, if i wanna change the base twice ?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI has calculation groups for exactly this scenario. Imagine you have a sales measure and want MTD, QTD and YTD variations. You could create 3 additional measures but what if you now need to do the same for purchases. You would then need 8 measures in total. Calculation groups allow you to do this with your two base measures and then a MTD, QTD, YTD variation placed on top automatically.

It is hard to provide exact code without a data model and an exact definition of all your measures but the following guides should be enough to get you started.

https://www.sqlbi.com/calculation-groups/